# How to write probability of $P(X<Z<Y)$ in the from of expected value of indicator function?

Tags: probability, expected-value

Suppose we have one exponential random variable $Z$ with rates $\lambda_z$ and two random variables $Y$ and $X$ with general distribution function, respectively. How can $P(X<Z<Y)$ be calculated as an expected value of indicator function or any other ways?

$E(1_{X<Z<Y})$ ?

Comment: Yup, that's how you do it

Comment: sorry, but i want to solve it in the form of expected value of indicator function

Comment: Does it help that $E(1_{X<Z<Y}) = E(1_{X<Z}) - E(1_{Z\geq Y})$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
E(1_{X<Z<Y}) &= \mathbb E_Z [1_{X<Z<Y}]\\
&= \mathbb E_X\left[\mathbb E_{Y|X}\left[\mathbb E_Z [1_{X=x<Z<Y=y}|X=x,Y=y]\right]\right]\\
\end{align*}
If $X,Y$ are independent, $\mathbb P [Y|X] = \mathbb P[Y]$. Further, since we are assuming exponential distribution, we have all variables $\in\mathbb R_+$. Then,
\begin{align*}
E(1_{X<Z<Y}) 
&= \mathbb E_X\left[\mathbb E_{Y}\left[\mathbb E_Z [1_{X=x<Z<Y=y}|X=x,Y=y]\right]\right]\\
&= \int\limits_{x=0}^\infty\left(\quad\int\limits_{y=x}^\infty E_Z [1_{X=x<Z<Y=y}|X=x,Y=y] f_Y(y)dy \right)f_X(x)dx\\
\end{align*}
This is in the form of an indicator function. We can further simpify this to
\begin{align*}
E(1_{X<Z<Y}) 
&= \int\limits_{x=0}^\infty\left(\quad\int\limits_{y=x}^\infty \left[CDF_{\lambda_z}(y) -CDF_{\lambda_z}(x)\right]f_Y(y)dy \right)f_X(x)dx\\
&= \int\limits_{x=0}^\infty\left(\quad\int\limits_{y=x}^\infty \left[\exp(-\lambda_zx)-\exp(-\lambda_zy)\right]f_Y(y)dy \right)f_X(x)dx\\
\end{align*}
Which we can solve if we know $f_X(x),f_Y(y)$

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear answer